# Combobox no muestran los datos en una tabla al buscarlos en Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, combobox

Tengo un problema cuando quiero mostrar los resultados en una tabla al buscarlos por 2 combobox.
Por medio del dump y el dd sé que el post funciona pero a la hora de hacer la consulta en base de datos siempre me arroja los mismos 3 registros pero, si la consulta la hago en mysql funciona correctamente, estoy confundida.

Cuando hago la búsqueda solo con dos inputs funciona correctamente, pero se necesita que sea con combobox y no entiendo el problema.

En mi controlador tengo el siguiente código:

```
public function buscarformulario()
{
    $organigramas =  Organigrama::all();
    $periodos = Periodo::all();

    return view('catalogodocente.plaza', compact('organigramas', 'periodos'));
}

public function buscarplaza(Request $request){
 
    $organigrama =trim($request->input('organigrama'));
    $periodo = trim($request->input('periodos')); 

    $organigramas = Organigrama::all();
    $periodos = Periodo::all();         
   
    $catalogodocentes=DB::table('horarios')
    ->join('catalogodocentes', 'horarios.rfc', '=', 'catalogodocentes.rfc')
    ->join('plaza_horas','catalogodocentes.rfc','=','plaza_horas.rfc')
    ->join('organigramas', 'catalogodocentes.clave_area', '=', 'organigramas.clave_area')
    ->join('grupos','horarios.codigo','=','grupos.codigo')
    ->join('periodos', 'horarios.periodo', '=', 'periodos.periodo' )
    
    ->select("horarios.rfc", "catalogodocentes.nombre_empleado", "organigramas.descripcion_area", 
    "catalogodocentes.apellidos_empleado", "plaza_horas.horas", "periodos.periodo", "grupos.paralelo_de",

    DB::raw("SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(CASE WHEN horarios.actividad = '11' THEN TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(TIME(horarios.hora_final), TIME(horarios.hora_inicial))) ELSE NULL END)) AS 'actividad_11'"),
    DB::raw("SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(CASE WHEN horarios.actividad = '113' THEN TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(TIME(horarios.hora_final), TIME(horarios.hora_inicial))) ELSE NULL END)) AS 'actividad_113'"),
    DB::raw("SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(CASE WHEN horarios.actividad = '12' THEN TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(TIME(horarios.hora_final), TIME(horarios.hora_inicial))) ELSE NULL END)) AS 'actividad_12'"),
    DB::raw("SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(CASE WHEN horarios.actividad = '161' THEN TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(TIME(horarios.hora_final), TIME(horarios.hora_inicial))) ELSE NULL END)) AS 'actividad_161'"),
    DB::raw("SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(CASE WHEN horarios.actividad = '163' THEN TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(TIME(horarios.hora_final), TIME(horarios.hora_inicial))) ELSE NULL END)) AS 'actividad_163'"),
    DB::raw("SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(CASE WHEN horarios.actividad = '164' THEN TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(TIME(horarios.hora_final), TIME(horarios.hora_inicial))) ELSE NULL END)) AS 'actividad_164'"),
    DB::raw("SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(CASE WHEN horarios.actividad = '166' THEN TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(TIME(horarios.hora_final), TIME(horarios.hora_inicial))) ELSE NULL END)) AS 'actividad_166'"),
    DB::raw("SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(CASE WHEN horarios.actividad = '17' THEN TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(TIME(horarios.hora_final), TIME(horarios.hora_inicial))) ELSE NULL END)) AS 'actividad_17'"),
    DB::raw("SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(CASE WHEN horarios.actividad = '181' THEN TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(TIME(horarios.hora_final), TIME(horarios.hora_inicial))) ELSE NULL END)) AS 'actividad_181'"),
    DB::raw("SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(CASE WHEN horarios.actividad = '183' THEN TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(TIME(horarios.hora_final), TIME(horarios.hora_inicial))) ELSE NULL END)) AS 'actividad_183'"),
    DB::raw("SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(CASE WHEN horarios.actividad = '186' THEN TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(TIME(horarios.hora_final), TIME(horarios.hora_inicial))) ELSE NULL END)) AS 'actividad_186'"),
    DB::raw("SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(CASE WHEN horarios.actividad = '187' THEN TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(TIME(horarios.hora_final), TIME(horarios.hora_inicial))) ELSE NULL END)) AS 'actividad_187'"),
    DB::raw("SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(CASE WHEN horarios.actividad = '191' THEN TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(TIME(horarios.hora_final), TIME(horarios.hora_inicial))) ELSE NULL END)) AS 'actividad_191'"),
    DB::raw("SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(CASE WHEN horarios.actividad = '192' THEN TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(TIME(horarios.hora_final), TIME(horarios.hora_inicial))) ELSE NULL END)) AS 'actividad_192'"),
    DB::raw("SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(CASE WHEN horarios.actividad = '193' THEN TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(TIME(horarios.hora_final), TIME(horarios.hora_inicial))) ELSE NULL END)) AS 'actividad_193'"),
    DB::raw("SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(CASE WHEN horarios.actividad = '23' THEN TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(TIME(horarios.hora_final), TIME(horarios.hora_inicial))) ELSE NULL END)) AS 'actividad_23'"),
    DB::raw("SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(CASE WHEN horarios.actividad = '282' THEN TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(TIME(horarios.hora_final), TIME(horarios.hora_inicial))) ELSE NULL END)) AS 'actividad_282'"),
    DB::raw("SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(CASE WHEN horarios.actividad = '298' THEN TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(TIME(horarios.hora_final), TIME(horarios.hora_inicial))) ELSE NULL END)) AS 'actividad_298'"),
    DB::raw("SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(CASE WHEN horarios.actividad = '299' THEN TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(TIME(horarios.hora_final), TIME(horarios.hora_inicial))) ELSE NULL END)) AS 'actividad_299'"),
    DB::raw("SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(CASE WHEN horarios.actividad = '30' THEN TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(TIME(horarios.hora_final), TIME(horarios.hora_inicial))) ELSE NULL END)) AS 'actividad_30'"),
    DB::raw("SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(CASE WHEN horarios.actividad = '303' THEN TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(TIME(horarios.hora_final), TIME(horarios.hora_inicial))) ELSE NULL END)) AS 'actividad_303'"),
    DB::raw("SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(CASE WHEN horarios.actividad = '330' THEN TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(TIME(horarios.hora_final), TIME(horarios.hora_inicial))) ELSE NULL END)) AS 'actividad_330'"),
    DB::raw("SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(CASE WHEN horarios.actividad = 'AA' THEN TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(TIME(horarios.hora_final), TIME(horarios.hora_inicial))) ELSE NULL END)) AS 'actividad_aa'"),
    DB::raw("SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(CASE WHEN horarios.actividad = 'AD' THEN TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(TIME(horarios.hora_final), TIME(horarios.hora_inicial))) ELSE NULL END)) AS 'actividad_ad'"),
    DB::raw("SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(CASE WHEN horarios.actividad = 'ANL' THEN TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(TIME(horarios.hora_final), TIME(horarios.hora_inicial))) ELSE NULL END)) AS 'actividad_anl'"),
    DB::raw("SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(CASE WHEN horarios.actividad = 'ARP' THEN TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(TIME(horarios.hora_final), TIME(horarios.hora_inicial))) ELSE NULL END)) AS 'actividad_arp'"),
    DB::raw("SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(CASE WHEN horarios.actividad = 'ART' THEN TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(TIME(horarios.hora_final), TIME(horarios.hora_inicial))) ELSE NULL END)) AS 'actividad_art'"),
    DB::raw("SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(CASE WHEN horarios.actividad = 'ATP' THEN TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(TIME(horarios.hora_final), TIME(horarios.hora_inicial))) ELSE NULL END)) AS 'actividad_atp'"),
    DB::raw("SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(CASE WHEN horarios.actividad = 'DOC' THEN TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(TIME(horarios.hora_final), TIME(horarios.hora_inicial))) ELSE NULL END)) AS 'actividad_doc'"),
    DB::raw("SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(CASE WHEN horarios.actividad = 'EE' THEN TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(TIME(horarios.hora_final), TIME(horarios.hora_inicial))) ELSE NULL END)) AS 'actividad_ee'"),
    DB::raw("SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(CASE WHEN horarios.actividad = 'EMD' THEN TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(TIME(horarios.hora_final), TIME(horarios.hora_inicial))) ELSE NULL END)) AS 'actividad_emd'"),
    DB::raw("SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(CASE WHEN horarios.actividad = 'EVE' THEN TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(TIME(horarios.hora_final), TIME(horarios.hora_inicial))) ELSE NULL END)) AS 'actividad_eve'"),
    DB::raw("SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(CASE WHEN horarios.actividad = 'JD' THEN TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(TIME(horarios.hora_final), TIME(horarios.hora_inicial))) ELSE NULL END)) AS 'actividad_jd'"),
    DB::raw("SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(CASE WHEN horarios.actividad = 'JP' THEN TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(TIME(horarios.hora_final), TIME(horarios.hora_inicial))) ELSE NULL END)) AS 'actividad_jp'"),
    DB::raw("SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(CASE WHEN horarios.actividad = 'PA' THEN TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(TIME(horarios.hora_final), TIME(horarios.hora_inicial))) ELSE NULL END)) AS 'actividad_pa'"),
    DB::raw("SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(CASE WHEN horarios.actividad = 'PI' THEN TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(TIME(horarios.hora_final), TIME(horarios.hora_inicial))) ELSE NULL END)) AS 'actividad_pi'"),
    DB::raw("SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(CASE WHEN horarios.actividad = 'PP' THEN TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(TIME(horarios.hora_final), TIME(horarios.hora_inicial))) ELSE NULL END)) AS 'actividad_pp'"),
    DB::raw("SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(CASE WHEN horarios.actividad = 'PPE' THEN TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(TIME(horarios.hora_final), TIME(horarios.hora_inicial))) ELSE NULL END)) AS 'actividad_ppe'"),
    DB::raw("SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(CASE WHEN horarios.actividad = 'PRM' THEN TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(TIME(horarios.hora_final), TIME(horarios.hora_inicial))) ELSE NULL END)) AS 'actividad_prm'"),
    DB::raw("SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(CASE WHEN horarios.actividad = 'RPI' THEN TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(TIME(horarios.hora_final), TIME(horarios.hora_inicial))) ELSE NULL END)) AS 'actividad_rpi'"),
    DB::raw("SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(CASE WHEN horarios.actividad = 'SA' THEN TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(TIME(horarios.hora_final), TIME(horarios.hora_inicial))) ELSE NULL END)) AS 'actividad_sa'"),
    DB::raw("SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(CASE WHEN horarios.actividad = 'T' THEN TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(TIME(horarios.hora_final), TIME(horarios.hora_inicial))) ELSE NULL END)) AS 'actividad_t'"),
    
    DB::raw('sum(timestampdiff(HOUR, hora_inicial, hora_final)) as horas_grupo'))
    
    ->where("horarios.tipo_horario", "=", 'Y')
    ->where("periodos.identificacion_corta", 'like', '%' .$periodo. '%')
    ->where("organigramas.descripcion_area", 'like', '%' .$organigrama. '%')

    ->groupBy("horarios.rfc")
    ->get();
    
    dump($request->all());
   
    return view('catalogodocente.plaza',compact('catalogodocentes','organigrama','periodo','organigramas','periodos'));
      
}
```

en mi vista la tengo de esta manera

```
<form action="{{route('catalogodocentes.buscarplaza')}} " method="post" role="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                @csrf    
                <div class="col-xl-12">
                        <div class="card row">
                            <div class="card-header" style="background-color: #c9dff0;">
                                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                                        <div class="input-group">
                                        <select name="@$organigramas['descripcion_area']" id="@$organigramas['descripcion_area']" class="form-control" 
                                         value="{{@$organigramas['descripcion_area']}}">
                                                @foreach ($organigramas as $organigrama)
                                                    <option name="organigrama['descripcion_area']" id="organigrama['descripcion_area']" 
                                                    value="{{ @$organigrama['descripcion_area'] }}"> {{@$organigrama['descripcion_area']}}</option>
                                                @endforeach
                                        </select>

                                        <select name="@$periodos['identificacion_corta']" id="@$periodos['identificacion_corta']" class="form-control" 
                                        value="{{@$periodos['identificacion_corta']}}">
                                                @foreach ($periodos as $periodo)
                                                    <option name="$periodo['identificacion_corta']" id="$periodo['identificacion_corta']" 
                                                    value="{{@$periodo['identificacion_corta']}}"> {{@$periodo['identificacion_corta']}}</option>
                                                @endforeach
                                        </select>

                                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Buscar">
```

Así las rutas

```
Route::get('/catalogodocente/buscar'[App\Http\Controllers\CatalogodocenteController::class,'buscarformulario'])->name('catalogodocentes.buscarformulario');

Route::post('/catalogodocente/buscarplaza'[App\Http\Controllers\CatalogodocenteController::class,'buscarplaza'])->name('catalogodocentes.buscarplaza');
```

Esto me arroja el dump y es lo que busco en el combobox
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Que te muestra el `dump($request->all());`?

Comment: El dump me manda un token y los datos que seleccione en los combobox cuando le doy buscar

Comment: Podrias mostrar un ejemplo? Sobre todo las claves del array de esos datos que seleccionaste

Comment: Edite mi pregunta, añadí lo que me manda el array, no se si a eso te refieres

Comment: Si, eso justamente. Nota que las claves del array son los nombres de los selects `<select name="@$organigramas['descripcion_area']"...` y `<select name="@$periodos['identificacion_corta']"`. pero en el controlador estas queriendo acceder a otros nombres `$organigrama =trim($request->input('organigrama'));` y `$periodo = trim($request->input('periodos'));`. Entonces, las variables `$organigrama` y `$periodo` que usas para tu consulta, probablemente valgan `null`

Comment: Te sugiero que pruebes ponerle un nombre mas amigable a tus selects, para que te sea mas facil acceder a ellos, por ejemplo, si les pones: `<select name="organigrama"...` y `<select name="periodo"`, en el controlador podras acceder a esos valores con `$organigrama = $request->input('organigrama');` y `$periodo = $request->input('periodo');`

Comment: Gracias ya funcionó, tengo otra duda como es para que el combobox mantenga el dato que seleccione? al momento de buscar

Comment: Vale. Lo voy a escribir en una respuesta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nota que las claves del array son los nombres de los selects

```php
<select name="@$organigramas['descripcion_area']"...
```

y

```php
<select name="@$periodos['identificacion_corta']"...
```

Pero en el controlador estas queriendo acceder a otros nombres

```php
$organigrama = trim($request->input('organigrama'));
```

y

```php
$periodo = trim($request->input('periodos'));
```

Entonces, las variables `$organigrama` y `$periodo` que usas para tu consulta, probablemente valgan `null`.

Te sugiero ponerle un nombre mas amigable a tus selects para que te sea mas facil acceder a ellos, por ejemplo, si les pones:

```php
<select name="organigrama"...
```

y

```php
<select name="periodo"...
```

En el controlador podras acceder a esos valores con:

```php
$organigrama = $request->input('organigrama');
```

y

```php
$periodo = $request->input('periodo');
```

Fuente: [Interacting With The Request. Accessing The Request](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/requests#accessing-the-request)

---

En respuesta a tu comentario *"tengo otra duda como es para que el combobox mantenga el dato que seleccione? al momento de buscar"*.

Para eso, puedes usar los valores seleccionados que devuelves desde el controlador. O sea, las variables `$organigrama` y `$periodo`:

```php
return view(
    'catalogodocente.plaza',
    compact(
        'catalogodocentes',
        'organigrama',
        'periodo',
        'organigramas',
        'periodos'
    )
);
```

para marcar el `option` correspondiente como `selected`:

```php
<select name="organigrama" id="organigrama" class="form-control">
    @foreach ($organigramas as $org)
    <option value="{{ $org['descripcion_area'] }}" @if($org['descripcion_area'] == $organigrama) selected @endif >
        {{ $org['descripcion_area'] }}
    </option>
    @endforeach
</select>

<select name="periodo" id="periodo" class="form-control">
    @foreach ($periodos as $per)
    <option value="{{ $per['identificacion_corta'] }}" @if($per['identificacion_corta'] == $periodo) selected @endif >
        {{ $per['identificacion_corta'] }}
    </option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

Nota que tuve que cambiar el nombre de la variable de cada elemento del loop para que no pise a la que devolviste desde el controlador (`$organigrama` por `$org` y `$periodo` por `$per`).

Basicamente, lo que hago es agregar un condicional que compare el valor del `option` actual con el que el controlador devolvio como el valor seleccionado, para agregarle el atributo `selected` a ese `option`, si la condicion es verdadera:

```
@if($org['descripcion_area'] == $organigrama) selected @endif

@if($per['identificacion_corta'] == $periodo) selected @endif
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por ayudarme, me funcionó